# Is using OnPropertyChanged(string.Empty); a practice to avoid?

Tags: xamarin.forms

We have `OnPropertyChanged(string.Empty);` in quite a few places in our Xamarin.Forms application. In general I feel like we shouldn't be saying "Hey, notify everyone that all the properties on this object have changed."

An example of where we do this is in some data syncing event handlers in a view model that inherits

```
    private void OnSyncEnding(object sender, EventArgs e){
        SyncItem = syncService.Value.SyncState;
        OnPropertyChanged(string.Empty);
    }
    private void OnSyncStarting(object sender, EventArgs e){
        SyncItem = syncService.Value.SyncState;
        OnPropertyChanged(string.Empty);
    }
    private void OnSyncFormSuccessful(object sender, EventArgs e){
        SyncItem = syncService.Value.SyncState;
        OnPropertyChanged(string.Empty);
    }
```

My question is: How much work does this actually trigger and when is using `OnPropertyChanged(string.Empty);` the correct thing to do instead of calling `OnPropertyChanged("SomeProperty")` for all the properties required?

Comment: I don't think that PropertyChanged is actually working because isn't tell which property change, i recommend you to use [PropertyChange Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) to handle for you.

Comment: If you don't want to notify it at all I'd remove `OnPropertyChanged(string.Empty);` either that or change it to properly notify your property with `OnPropertyChanged("SomeProperty")` or better yet `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SomeProperty))`

Comment: @FabriBertani in Xamarin.Forms passing an empty string means "all properties on the object". and PropertyChange Fody looks really awesome.